# Mixed model regression with non-independent (nested?) data in r

Tags: r, nested-data, regression, lme4-nlme

I am having trouble modeling a regression with seemingly non-independent, nested observations. I am examining the effect of relatedness on proportion of offspring in cases of multiple males contributing to a brood of eggs. I have estimates of the genetic relatedness between each male and the female it mated with, as well as the proportion of offspring a male sired in that female's brood of eggs. There are up to 5 males contributing to a brood, and 9 broods sampled for paternity.

So the outcome is proportion sired, and the dependent variable is relatedness. Seems straightforward. However, the observations of male offspring proportion are not independent within a brood (the proportions sum to 1).  Should observations be nested within female, or should female be treated as a random effect (9 broods from 9 females) or both?And should Relatedness remain a fixed effect?

I only have one predictor and one outcome, proportion ~ relatedness, so I initially thought it would be relatively simple, but the female "treatment" is random...and male data within a female are not really independent.  I am looking to do this analysis in lme4 in R.

Here is an example of the data:

```
ID  Female  Relat.  Prop.
1   A        .12      .3
2   A        .03      .02
3   B         .02      .33
```

...
Thanks for any help or advice,
LP

Comment: cross-posted to [r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org](https://mailman.stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2014q1/021527.html) ; some of us prefer it if you pick one venue or the other, rather than cross-posting ...

Comment: yes, sorry! I didnt know of the r-sig-mixed list until after I posted here.